# Get SUMs for dimension record from several fact tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to 2 queries below which calculate to correct value:

```
Select Finances.CustomerID,
sum(Finances.Total)Total
from Finances
group by Finances.CustomerID
order by Finances.CustomerID
```

---

```
Select Invoices.CustomerID,
sum(Invoices.InvoiceValue)InvoiceValue
from Invoices
group by Invoices.CustomerID
order by Invoices.CustomerID
```

within the Finances table a customer can owe money from multiple orders, so for this example lets say the customer has to pay £100+ £400 + £500, which totals to £1000.

the customer then receives the 1st invoice for £100, and pays this..

so the 2nd query would now display £100.... from these 2 values I then want to calculate a 3rd column which deducts the £100 away from the £1000 equalling £900 (the amount left to pay)

the is my table structure:

[image]

there are a lot more tables associated however this is where I am the data from with the select statements :)

how would i write the sql statement to do this all together or is it not possible? ideally i would like the to be used within a INSERT -> SELECT -> WHERE NOT EXISTS Statement or alternatively populated in a view. thanks for the help

SAMPLE DATA:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerFinances AS
    ;WITH FinancesCTE AS
    (
        Select Finances.CustomerID,
        sum(Finances.Total)Total
        from Finances
        group by Finances.CustomerID
    ),InvoicesCTE AS
    (
        Select Invoices.CustomerID,
        sum(Invoices.InvoiceValue)InvoiceValue
        from Invoices
        group by Invoices.CustomerID
    )
    SELECT C.*,
           F.Total AS FinanceTotal,
           I.InvoiceValue
    FROM   Customers C
           LEFT JOIN FinancesCTE F
               ON C.CustomerID = F.CustomerID
           LEFT JOIN InvoicesCTE I
               ON C.CustomerID = I.CustomerID

GO
```

Comment: what does the "; WITH FinancesCTE" AS mean? is FinancesCTE the name of the new table/view?

and thanks for the help

Comment: It is a common table expression. Details http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx . You may wrap this in a view. I will update my answer.

Comment: its returning millions of results... by the looks of it associates all Finances.Total, Invoices.Value from all CustomerID's

Comment: First of all, add a `WHERE` clause when you are running your view. As i see it, it should get one row for each customer. A bit of sample data would help.

Comment: OH I SAW THE ERROR!!!!! It is on the first Join C.CustomerId = C.CustomerId. I will update.

Comment: perfect, cheers for the help... would have taken me forever to solve that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60681/discussion-between-crezzer7-and-giannis-paraskevopoulos).

Comment: oh, it wont let me create it as a view.. the last select * statement contains CustomerID 3 times and it doesnt like the duplicate column header

Comment: Check the edit. I am in the chat too if you need me.

Comment: The reason it didn't let you was having multiple columns with the same name. In my last edit i get all the columns from Customers and just the totals of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this,

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerFinanceDetails AS 
(

 select c.*,isnull(FinanceTotal,0) as FinanceTotal,isnull(InvoiceTotal,0) as InvoiceTotal 
 from 
 (select * from Customers) c
   left outer join 
 (select CustomerID,isnull(SUM(Total),0) as FinanceTotal from Finances group by CustomerID) f on c.CustumerID=f.CustomerID
   left outer join 
 (select CustomerID,isnull(SUM(InvoiceValue),0) as InvoiceTotal from Invoices group by CustomerID) i on c.CustumerID= i.CustomerID

)
```